# Adobe InDesign - Editing the list of character colors suggested under Character Style > Character Color

Tags: adobe-indesign

[image: Screenshot of character style options men, with character color selected in the submenu. The character color swatch options are circled in red - this is what I'm referring to.]

I'd like to know if there is a way to delete or modify the color swatches that show up under character style options > character color. Even better would be if I could connect these swatches to a CC Library.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I should have looked a bit further! I just answered my own question.

Rather than editing these from character / paragraph style menus, color swatches can be edited by clicking on an object in the file, going to the properties panel, and clicking appearance > fill. Swatches can be deleted from that menu. This will also delete them in character color settings.

Comment: There is also a **Swatch Panel**.